# sending automatic email newsletter from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to be able to send an automatic email message to those who complete a google form .  There responses are fed to a google spreadsheet, and I'd like to be able to set it up so that anytime someone completes the form, they are sent the email.  Any idea how to do this?  I've tried the google tutorial about sending emails from a spreadsheet, but since this is not an automatic function, it does not suit my needs.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you post the code ? If your function is called onSubmit() it will be called automatically

Answer (score 0):

Create an installable trigger in the Form to run for the `on Form Submit` event.  Use a function like `getFormDataFields` to grab the data from the form submission event.  Use the `MailApp.sendEmail` function to blast out an email.  Provide it the necessary parameters.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var data = getFormDataFields(e);  //data['Question Name']
  MailApp.sendEmail();
}

function getFormDataFields(e){
    var dataFields = [];
    for (property in e.namedValues){
        dataFields[property] = e.namedValues[property][0];
    }
    return dataFields;
}
```